# Trouble calling methods in Class

Tags: python, class, methods

I'm having trouble calling methods in a class written by someone else (https://github.com/travishathaway/python-ach/blob/master/ach/parser.py). I have done some research but don't fully understand how to call methods with `self` and other arguments within a class.

The class is written out in the link above, but how do I call any of the methods written out? I have a file in the correct format asked but I cannot get the methods to work. For example, I have tried (and other variations):

```py
a = Parser(file)  # where "file" is the filepath

a.__parse_file_header()
```

This gives me the error: 'Parser' object has no attribute '__parse_file_header'

Comment: A name starting with double underscores like that is private, intended for use only from within the class.  The actual method you're intended to use is probably something like `.parse()`, read the documentation for the class.

Comment: Methods with names starting with an underscore generally are not meant to be called from outside. You are supposed to use just `.as_json` or `.as_dict`. This isn't a very well-designed class, though, which is to say, it probably shouldn't be a class at all.

Comment: Hi @KarlKnechtel can you please explain why it shouldn't be a class? Just being curious and want to learn more best practise.

Comment: [Jack Diederich hammers home the lesson here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o9pEzgHorH0). The point is that the class doesn't represent a coherent thing-with-behaviour; it basically just wraps up a complex process and offers you a different output format at the end. You would only ever use this class by constructing an instance, calling either `.as_json` or `.as_dict`, and then throwing it away. That logic could just as easily be implemented using plain functions, with no loss of convenience.

Answer (score 2):

The methods with 2 underscores in the front are "private" to the class object itself, which is not supposed to be called externally. (Saying that you can still call private methods if you really want to, via [mangling](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/private-methods-in-python/))

By the look of the `Parser`, you should only call `as_json` or `as_dict` of the Parser object you initiated with the string variable

eg.

```py
parser = Parser(string_variable)
dict = parser.as_dict()
```

Comment: Thanks James! My issue was I was putting the file path in the object of the parser instead of a string variable. Clear explanation I appreciate it!

Comment: No problem, glad I could help.